# What's wrong with my Python code

Tags: python

```
C1 = ("NeQua")
C2 = ("ImKol")
C3 = ("YoTri")
C3 = ("RoDen")
C4 = ("NaThe")
C5 = ("ReWes")
C6 = ("BrFre")
C7 = ("KaDat")
C8 = ("ViRil")
C9 = ("TrGeo")
C10 = ("DaWay")
C11 = ("CaAma")
C12 = ("ArRes")
C13 = ("BeVic")
C14 = ("MaFre")
C15 = ("AnMer")
C16 = ("SaBro")
C17 = ("PoLig")
C18 = ("HeZbe")
C19 = ("GiLop")
C20 = ("DeTur")
C21 = ("LaKin")
C23 = ("LoLew")
C24 = ("NyRed")

the_ID = input("Please enter your client ID")

if the_ID == 'C1' or 'C2' or 'C3' or 'C4' or 'C5' or 'C6' or 'C7' or 'C8' or 'C9' or 'C10' or 'C12' or 'C13' or 'C14' or 'C15' or 'C16' or 'C17' or 'C18' or 'C19' or 'C20' or 'C21' or 'C22' or 'C23' or 'C24':
    print ("Access Granted")
else:
    print ("Access Denied")
```

So if your ID is one of them you get the access but otherwise you don't. E.g. If write KaDat it will say access granted because it's in `C7`.

But if I write `gibirish` like `gsubivdse` it will say access denied because its not in any of the variables.

No matter what I type I keep getting access granted. What's wrong with my code?

Yes im a noob at programing :(
nvm i got it to work now with a few changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is broken enough I have to say. You compare `the_ID` with the string `'C1'` instead of the value of `C1`. You should also look up how the `or` works.

At minimum I would write something like `the_ID` in :

```
[C1, C2, C3]
```